# Haskell Lists of Maybe Int's, convert each element to char, then String

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, char, option-type

Need help with a haskell problem thats doing my head in. I know the steps (sorta) that need to be taken to achieve want I want but I don't really know how to go about doing it.

E.g

Say I have a lists of `Maybe Int`'s - `[[Just 2, Nothing, Just 3],[Just 6,Just 3, Just 3],[Nothing,Nothing, Just 1]]`

I need to create a function that.

1) Takes lists of `Maybe Int`s

```
[[Just 2, Nothing, Just 3],[Just 6,Just 3, Just 3],[Nothing,Nothing, Just 1]]
```

2) Gets First List (`head`?)

```
[Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]
```

3) Recurse through each element within the list - `(x:xs)`

```
Just 2, Nothing, Just 3
```

4) convert `Maybe Int` to a `Char` - `fromEnum`

```
'2', '   ', '3'
```

5) return the complete `String` containing all the chars - `(++) = [char] / String`

```
"2   3"
```

6) move onto the next List until list = `[]`

```
[Just 6,Just 3, Just 3]
```

So the end result would be something like this printed out on a separate line:

```
"2   3"
"633"
"     1"
```

I tried to explain it as well as possible and any tips / helps / sources of information would be appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, you keep saying you want to operate on a list of Maybe Ints, but your examples each have Lists of List Maybe Int. Ie [[Maybe Int]]

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `maybe` function, which allows you apply a function to the value in a `Just` with a default if it was `Nothing`, so to convert a `Maybe Int` to a single-digit `Char` with space as the default, use `maybe ' ' intToDigit`. (`toEnum` would use the ASCII value, which is not what you want here).

Then, to apply that within a list of lists, you just use `map` twice:

```
> import Data.Char
> map (map $ maybe ' ' intToDigit) [[Just 2, Nothing, Just 3],[Just 6,Just 3, Just 3], [Nothing, Nothing, Just 1]]
["2 3","633","  1"]
```

Since a string is just a list of characters, the result is a list of strings.

Comment: After you're done, you print it with unlines.  So the whole thing should be unlines. map (map $ maybe ' ' intToDigit) $ [your list]